# Converting into Normalization form C in php

Tags: php, icu

I have a need to convert source data that I can't control into normalization form C. I am currently doing it, but by calling an external program (`uconv`). This is what my code snippet looks like:

```
$malayalam_books = preg_split("/\n/", shell_exec("uconv -f utf8 -t utf8 -x nfc book-names.txt"));
```

It works well, but obviously making calls to the system is not recommended. I know that [PHP supports the ICU libraries](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.intl.php), but it's so convoluted how to do a simple thing like this...

Comment: And what's your question or problem?

Comment: Have you checked `iconv*` functions? http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois I guess since I flagged the question with "php" I thought it would be obvious that my question or problem is how to achieve this using php without relying on the use of shell_exec. But maybe it wasn't so obvious...

Comment: You should probably read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois thanks for the advice.

Comment: @marekful I did look at iconv but I didn't have success. I have a suitable workaround in place now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since discovered that the [normalizer_normalize](http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php) PECL function can handle this natively in PHP 5 >= 5.3.0.